# Crawlable ajax pages

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I've read about Google and Google's possibility to crawl ajax pages using hash followed by a exclamation mark in the url, #!

( http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html )

I have changed my website and I was wondering about Google Analytics. How do I track my visitors ajax requests?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics has a `_trackPageview` function that you can call when you load content via AJAX to record a pageview. There's details in this [Google Analytics Help topic](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/thread?tid=3b27f20bd196102a&hl=en) and undoubtedly more in the GA docs.

Comment: Can I include a hash char in the line, something like pageTracker._trackPageview('/page#!something'); ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Give it a try and find out?

Comment: I sure will. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Google just deprecated the need for the #! scheme.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

They state:

> Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers.

So now you wont really need to track anything different in Analytics!